# Best way to program buttons/images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing something that will have a homepage close to the Google+ android app.

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do this? Should I create a button with text and set the background as the image? Should I create an image with the text already programmed in the actual picture or should I program the text and picture to be buttons.

Any suggestions from you guys on past projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am a newbie in android development I may be wrong but I suggest why not use a Grid View with each grid item haaving a textview and imageview.

Comment: +1 correct although TableLayout can be used but that will make the code more complicated

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Button with text to whatever you like and then place the image for that button above the text (using `android:drawableTop`)like so:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/imageButton"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Photos"
     android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_image" />
```

replacing `buttton_image` with your actual image. If you want the image in a different position (i.e. below text etc) use:

```
android:drawableLeft
android:drawableRight
android:drawableBottom
```

This would be how I would and do do it...

Comment: You can also use padding (see android:drawablePadding="") etc, to make it more like the above examples, but figured you didn't need help with that! :)

Comment: +1 Also agree with this solution. I think this is also the best one.

Answer (score 1):

My suggest to layout:
If you want to try something new in Android 4.0 , you can try GridLayout to layout , it can reduce the complicate of the nested layout , check out the blog about GridLayout:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/11/new-layout-widgets-space-and-gridlayout.html

Answer (score 1):

You should write Buttons this way: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html

I normally use RelativeLayout but this is not important.

Write a class `myClass extends RelativeLayout` and inflate the XML with

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myCustomLayout, this, true);
```

I think this is best practice by Google.

Answer (score 0):

use a regular button and set the android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_...." value

Answer (score 0):

Having the text burnt into you image is most certainly not the way to go.

One option for you is a GridView. You could also do this through a combination of Image button and scrollview. In my opinion, GridView is best and involves the least amount of code with most flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can replace the button's background image with a [state list drawable.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)